# How to hook into Add New Member in BuddyPress

Tags: hooks

I have a hook into the WordPress Add New User process via an `add_action('user_register', 'doMyFunction');` hook.

What results is that I am (Step 1) adding a new user through WordPress and then (Step 2) having to add the same user to BuddyPress in order to get the user fully activated in WP/BP with the proper role.

I would prefer to just add a new user/member once through the Buddy Press Add User page and have it go through my hooked function.

Is there a Buddypress hook I should change too on the hook I show above in order to eliminate the 1st step described in my process?

Thanks for helping.

**Expanding for better clarity**

We do not use the BuddyPress signup process. We (as an Admin) setup new users ourselves. The reason is we have our own login authentication system that all users must pass through.

So I have hooked into WP's `add_user` in order to (1) programmatically capture the user id I am creating and write it externally to our authentication systems' list of vald users and (2) send a custom email to the user newly created.

Then I have to go into the BuddyPress admin page and setup the new user again so I can assign their role and let BP know they are good to go.

I would much rather hook right into BuddyPress' add new user and do my external write and launch my custom email. I have tested and I know that the Add New User in BP adds it to WP as well.

I just don't know what BP's hook is -- the one comparable to WP' s `add_user`.

*Hope that clarifies.*

Comment: Why are you not adding the user directly in BP as it automatically synchs with WP?

Comment: I need to get in the process @kalengi because I capture the user id and write to a flat file for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the user id when a user is registered, hook into `bp_core_signup_user`:

```
add_action('bp_core_signup_user', 'doMyFunction', 10, 5);

function doMyFunction($user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta){
    //do stuff
}
```

It supplies the user id as the first parameter.

Comment: Hmm, my question is not worded well if it generates that solution @kalengi. I am adding to it in the original question for better clarity. Give me a moment to post.

Comment: Hey @kalengi, let me know if you have a solution here. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you add the user in the BP admin page?

Comment: See my revision to my initial question above @kalengi. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is: Which menu options do you click to get there? Can't seem to locate any BP admin page that adds users.

Comment: Oh, sorry @kalengi. Go to {Dashboard} > Users > Add New >> I have to use the Add Existing User form. My preference is to use the Add New User form (only once...here on this page).

Comment: How do you get the Add Existing User form? Did you enable a setting or install a plugin? Also, since user info on BP is maintained by XProfile, you could check whether it triggers any hooks when you add the user.

Comment: Hmmm, well I did not enable any particular setting knowingly @kalengi. I simply figured out how to add new users to BuddyPress by stepping through the process I laid out in my question above. I get to the BP add Existing User form by {Dashboard} > Users > Add New >> Add Existing User form which is on the page. Also, you state "since user info on BP is maintained by XProfile, you could check whether it triggers any hooks when you add the user" -- how do I check triggers for hooks?

Comment: believe me sir, i've clicked all you've described and no Add Existing User form exists on my end. On how to check triggers, look for all the `do_action()` calls in that module.

Comment: Thanks @kalengi. I will post a couple answers below to share more insight. Stay tuned. And thanks for sticking with this one...

Comment: this fires after a user is registered,  is it possible to catch before a user set into dB?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly to help anyone that looks here and tries to take away that `bp_core_signup_user` is the solution...well, it isn't (at least for me in what I am trying to accomplish).

In my plugin I simply replaced:
`add_action('user_register', 'rebuildAuthUsers'); // rebuild the authorized user list anytime a new user is created through WordPress`

with:
`add_action('bp_core_signup_user', 'rebuildAuthUsers'); // rebuild the authorized user list anytime a new user is created through BuddyPress`

It did not intercept the registration process and launch my function.

Still digging...